# How to merge and sort nested sub-documents with aggregation in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate, subdocument

Consider, I have these three example schema
Where mainScheam is the actual document and other schemas ("activitySchema", "essentialSchema") are sub-documents.

I have used pseudo types in Schemas just for example purpose and clear understanding

Schemas

```js
let activitySchema = new Schema({
    "_id":ObjectID,
    "title":string,
    "created_at":new Date(),
    "created_by":ObjectID,
});

let essentialSchema = new Schema({
    "_id":ObjectID,
    "activity":[activitySchema],
    "created_at":new Date(),
    "created_by":ObjectID,
});

let mainSchema = new Schema({
    "_id":ObjectID,
    "name":string,
    "activity":[activitySchema],
    "essential":[essential],
    "created_at": new Date(),
    "created_by":ObjectID,
}); 

let Main = mongoose.model("main", mainSchema);
```

Main Document in Database is similar to this

```js
{
    "id":"...",
    "name":"rpc",
    "activity":[{
        "_id":"...",
        "title":"abc de",
        "created_at":12345...,
        "created_by":"...",
    }, {
        "_id":"...",
        "title":"defg",
        "created_at":12467...,
        "created_by":"...",
    }],
    "essential":[{
        "_id":"...",
        "activity":[{
            "_id":"...",
            "title":"usidl kdsl",
            "created_at":2128...,
            "created_by":"...",
        }],
        "created_at":2125...,
        "created_by":"...",
    }],
    "created_at":2105...,
    "created_by":"...",
}
```

Now I have to find out the latest/recent activity from the above mainSchema and sub documents
From above example I have to return sorted activity according to created_at time.

```js
{
    "_id":"...",
    "title":"usidl kdsl",
    "created_at":2128...,
    "created_by":"...",
}
```

I am using aggregate but don't know how to achieve my goal?

```js
const mains = await Main.aggregate([
    {
        $project:{
            "name":"$name",
            "last_activity":sort("$activity", "$essential.activity"), //-- This is the part where I don't know what to do
            "created_at":"$created_at",
        },
    }
]);
```

Comment: Hope this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23942229/5483415) helps. Similar question.

Comment: @rohit-w no it doesn't help.